# Python simulation shows slow performance, how to speed array calculation up

Tags: python, c++, arrays, performance

I'm trying to write a simple Python program which calculates the interference pattern from 2 incoming laser beams. Everything is working as it should but it's quite slow. I'm using a 400x400 array and it takes about 1.3 seconds to recalculate the intensity after I change a parameter. However, running the code with C++ takes about 0.18 seconds. So I'm wondering if I could improve something to speed things up?

My code so far:

```
def calculate_intensity_array():
    laser1 = zeros((400, 400), dtype=complex)
    laser2 = zeros((400, 400), dtype=complex)
    data = zeros((400, 400), dtype=complex)

    onoff_1 = laser1_onoff_var.get()
    A_1 = laser1_intensity_var.get()
    sigma_1 = laser1_sigma_var.get()
    sin_phi_1 = sin((laser1_phi_var.get() / 180) * pi)
    cos_phi_1 = cos((laser1_phi_var.get() / 180) * pi)
    sin_theta_1 = sin((laser1_theta_var.get() / 180) * pi)
    cos_theta_1 = cos((laser1_theta_var.get() / 180) * pi)
    mu_x_1 = laser1_xpos_var.get()
    mu_y_1 = laser1_ypos_var.get()

    onoff_2 = laser2_onoff_var.get()
    A_2 = laser2_intensity_var.get()
    sigma_2 = laser2_sigma_var.get()
    sin_phi_2 = sin((laser2_phi_var.get() / 180) * pi)
    sin_theta_2 = sin((laser2_theta_var.get() / 180) * pi)
    cos_phi_2 = cos((laser2_phi_var.get() / 180) * pi)
    cos_theta_2 = cos((laser2_theta_var.get() / 180) * pi)
    mu_x_2 = laser2_xpos_var.get()
    mu_y_2 = laser2_ypos_var.get()


    if onoff_1 == 0:
        laser1 = zeros((400, 400), dtype=complex)
    elif onoff_1 == 1:
        for i in range(400):
            for k in range(400):    
                laser1[i][k] = calculate_amplitude(
                    (k - 200) * 10,
                    (i - 200) * 10,
                    A_1, 
                    sigma_1, 
                    sin_phi_1,
                    cos_phi_1,
                    sin_theta_1,
                    cos_theta_1,
                    mu_x_1,
                    mu_y_1)

    if onoff_2 == 0:
        laser2 = zeros((400, 400), dtype=complex)
    elif onoff_2 == 1:
        for i in range(400):
            for k in range(400):         
                laser2[i][k] = calculate_amplitude(
                    (k - 200) * 10,
                    (i - 200) * 10,
                    A_2,
                    sigma_2,
                    sin_phi_2,
                    cos_phi_2,
                    sin_theta_2,
                    cos_theta_2,
                    mu_x_2,
                    mu_y_2)

    data = abs(laser1 + laser2) ** 2

    return data

def calculate_amplitude(x, y, A, sigma, sin_phi, cos_phi, 
                        sin_theta, cos_theta, mu_x, mu_y):

    amplitude = A * (1 / (sqrt(2  * pi * (sigma ** 2 / cos_theta ** 2)))) *
                exp(-((cos_phi *(x - mu_x) + sin_phi *(y - mu_y)) ** 2 * cos_theta ** 2) /
                    (2 * sigma ** 2)) * 
                (1 / (sqrt(2 * pi * sigma ** 2))) * 
                exp(-((-sin_phi * (x - mu_x) + cos_phi * (y - mu_y)) ** 2) / 
                    (2 * sigma ** 2)) * 
                cmath.exp(1j *(2 * pi / 0.650) * sin_theta * 
                          (cos_phi * (x - mu_x) + sin_phi * (y - mu_y)))


    return amplitude

start = time.clock()
draw_data = calculate_intensity_array()
print time.clock()-start
```

Perhaps there is something that catches your eye that should be done different? The main calculation happens in calculate_amplitude, but I tried to input only sin, cos values, such that they don't have to be evaluated each time again.

The C++ equivalent looks like:

```
void calculate_intensity_array()
{
    double intensity_array[400][400];
    static complex<double> laser1[400][400];
    static complex<double> laser2[400][400];

    double A1 = 1;
    double sigma1 = 2000;
    double cos_theta1 = 0.9999619;
    double sin_theta1 = 0.00872654;
    double cos_phi1 = 1;
    double sin_phi1 = 0;
    double mu_x1 = 0.0;
    double mu_y1 = 0.0;

    double A2 = 1;
    double sigma2 = 2000;
    double cos_theta2 = 0.9999619;
    double sin_theta2 = 0.00872654;
    double cos_phi2 = 1;
    double sin_phi2 = 0;
    double mu_x2 = 0.0;
    double mu_y2 = 0.0;

    for (int i=0; i<400; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<400; j++)
        {
            laser1[i][j] = calculate_amplitude((i-200)*10, (j-200)*10, A1, 
                                               sigma1, sin_phi1, cos_phi1, 
                                               sin_theta1, cos_theta1, 
                                               mu_x1, mu_y1);

            laser2[i][j]=calculate_amplitude((i-200)*10, (j-200)*10, A2, 
                                             sigma2, sin_phi2, cos_phi2, 
                                             sin_theta2, cos_theta2, 
                                             mu_x2, mu_y2);

            intensity_array[i][j] = pow(abs(laser1[i][j] + laser2[i][j]), 2);
        }
    }
}

complex<double> calculate_amplitude(double x, double y, double A,
                                    double sigma, double sin_phi,
                                    double cos_phi, double sin_theta,
                                    double cos_theta, double mu_x,
                                    double mu_y)
{
    complex<double> output;
     output = A * (1 / (sqrt(2 * M_PI * pow(sigma / cos_theta, 2)))) *
            exp(-(pow(cos_phi * (x - 200 - mu_x) + sin_phi * (y - 200 - mu_y), 2) * 
            pow(cos_theta, 2)) / (2 * pow(sigma, 2))) * 
            (1 / (sqrt(2 * M_PI * pow(sigma, 2)))) * 
            exp(-(pow(-sin_phi * (x - 200 - mu_x) + cos_phi * 
                (y - 200 - mu_y), 2)) / (2 * pow(sigma, 2))) *
            exp(complex<double>(0, (2 * M_PI / 0.650) * sin_theta *
                (cos_phi * (x - 200 - mu_x) + sin_phi * (y - 200 - mu_y))));

    return output;
}
```

Comment: First thing that comes to mind: C++ probably inlines the function call, Python can't do that.

Comment: Use `numpy` lib, and `pypy`...

Comment: I think Terran's suggestion is valid. I would also recommend using `Matlab` for this sort of thing, instead of python.

Comment: If you want to improve performance, *start* by using a profiler or carefully placed instrumentation (interval measurement or timestamp trace) to see which bits take most of the time.  S.O. is not a code review site, and your problem's not specific.  Separately, what's it got to do with python?  Was that just mentioned for historical interest and performance comparison?  If you want C++ speed but still want data in python, you can expose the C++ function in a shared library - see python's C/API.

Comment: `calculate_amplitude` is literally the stuff of my nightmares.

Comment: In the python code, you're using range for the loops; the arrays are iterable, so you should be able to use ``for l, row in enumerate(laser):`` as the outside loop, with ``for k, col in enumerate(row):`` for the inner loop. Should help slightly, because range generates a list of numbers.

Comment: alright, thanks for your suggestions. I already used numpy and I want to use python and not matlab because it's actually meant to be a matlab alternative. So that's why I mentioned python. I compared it to C++ because the speed was much faster there...
Thanks Mike P, I'll try your hint and change range.
I think another way of improving the performance is to calculate all values which are independent of x and y (which are iterated) and just pass less values as they won't have to be computed every time again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn your code into C++ automagically!

The following python code looks like yours:

```
#pythran export loop(int, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float)
from math import exp, sqrt, pi
import cmath
from numpy import empty

def loop(n,A, sigma, sin_phi, cos_phi,
                                 sin_theta, cos_theta, mu_x, mu_y):
    out = empty((n,n), dtype=complex)
    for x in range(n):
        for y in range(n):
            out[x,y] = calculate_amplitude(x,y,A, sigma, sin_phi, cos_phi,
                                           sin_theta, cos_theta, mu_x, mu_y)
    return out

def calculate_amplitude(x, y, A, sigma, sin_phi, cos_phi,
                        sin_theta, cos_theta, mu_x, mu_y):

    amplitude = (A * (1 / (sqrt(2  * pi * (sigma ** 2 / cos_theta ** 2)))) *
                 exp(-((cos_phi *(x - mu_x) + sin_phi *(y - mu_y)) ** 2 * cos_theta ** 2) /
                     (2 * sigma ** 2)) *
                 (1 / (sqrt(2 * pi * sigma ** 2))) *
                 exp(-((-sin_phi * (x - mu_x) + cos_phi * (y - mu_y)) ** 2) /
                     (2 * sigma ** 2)) *
                 cmath.exp(1j *(2 * pi / 0.650) * sin_theta *
                           (cos_phi * (x - mu_x) + sin_phi * (y - mu_y))))


    return amplitude
```

Then compiling it with pythran:

```
$ pythran laser.py
```

And run it through timeit:

```
$ python -m timeit -s 'import laser' 'laser.loop(20,1,200,0.9,0.08,1,.5,.5,2)'
10000 loops, best of 3: 84.7 usec per loop
```

While the original code ran in:

```
$ python -m timeit -s 'import laser' 'laser.loop(20,1,200,0.9,0.08,1,.5,.5,2)'
100 loops, best of 3: 2.65 msec per loop
```

You can probably achieve a similar result with [numba](http://numba.pydata.org) or [cython](http://cython.org) :-)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, that's awesome! With numba one calculation takes now 0.19 seconds which is pretty close to the C++ speed :)
I only had to replace calculate_amplitude with
        `calculate_amplitude_jit = numba.jit("c8(f8,f8,f8,f8,f8,f8,f8,f8,f8,f8,)")(calculate_amplitude)`